# Custom validation summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the UpdateModel method for validation. How do I specify the text for the error messages as they appear in the validation summary?

---

Sorry, I wasn't entirely clear. When I call UpdateModel(), if there is parsing error, for example if a string value is specified for a double field, a "SomeProperty is invalid" error message is automatically added to the ModelState.

How do I specify the text for said *automatically* generated error message?

If I implement IDataErrorInfo as suggested, it's error message property gets called for *every* column, regardless of whether the default binder deems it valid or not.

I'd have to reimplement the parse error catching functionality that I get for free with the default binder.

Incidentally, the default "SomeProperty is invalid" error messages seem to have mysteriously dissappeared in the RC. A validation summary appears and the relevant fields are highlighted but the text is missing! Any idea why this is?

Thanks again and I hope all this waffle makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/03/05/validation-with-aspnet-mvc-xval-idataerrorinfo/) is a good example of the `IDataErrorInfo` technique - it makes adding validation parameters easy by adding them as attributes directly to the properties of the model classes.

[These](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-29-cs.aspx) [examples](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx) also may help - slightly different approaches to validating.

Additionally, [this creative idea (which also implements `IDataErrorInfo`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721327/validate-object-based-on-external-factors-ie-data-store-uniqueness/1741831#1741831) may be a help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IDataErrorInfo` on your model.