# What is the best way to write a validation layer for SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm using an ADO.net provider of SQLite. I want to steer around some of the "features" of SQLite, like allowing a string in an integer field and allowing a string longer than n in a field of type varchar(n). What is the best way to achieve this kind of validation? Stored procedures? triggers? I'm looking for a generic solution that applies to any database not just my database schema.

Comment: In "corporate" enviroments, what you propose would be considered bugs, not features.

Comment: That's why features is quoted. Take a look here http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3

Comment: Can you modify the ADO.NET provider?

Comment: Yes the provider's source is available, could you give some sample code?

Comment: Not yet. :) I'd have to look at the source and see where some validation code could be punched in.  Which ADO.NET provider is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add column constraints.

```
create table example
( 
  age integer not null check (typeof(age)='integer'),
  name text not null check (length(name) between 1 and 100),
  salary integer check (salary is null or typeof(salary)='integer')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience is that what you're worried about is almost never a problem.  When it is, the problem is due to grossly wrong code (inserting mothersmaidenname into age or something).  The best way of keeping it 'not a problem' is to have (and use) good data access layers which effectively abstract the database.

Answer (score 0):

Validate in your c# [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POCO) objects rather than in the SQLite db using something like `DataAnnotations` or maybe even [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721327/validate-object-based-on-external-factors-ie-data-store-uniqueness/1741831#1741831).