# Less Linq to SQL and more Repository way to provide Rule Violations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, validation

In the nerd dinner, they use partial keywords to overload the Linq to SQL classes to embed the data validation.

Let's say you want to data validate exclusively in the repository.  Is there some website link out there that shows how to construct this in a way that can feed the Html.Validation helpers seamlessly?

I heard this is changing a bit in MVC 2 so that you can completely do this client side with JQuery while still using the server side Repository rules.  Any links on how to construct the data validation in the Repository would be great too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721327/validate-object-based-on-external-factors-ie-data-store-uniqueness/1741831#1741831).